# Second value of array is not written by openCSV to file, especially when jar is executed within a shell file but working fine on IDE

Tags: bash, shell, intellij-idea, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink java program which produces 2 outputs which I want to write in the file . I am using OpenCSV 4.0 for this and it is working well. Let's say the output file should be x,y where x and y are two outputs. I am getting this output when I run this program from IntelliJ IDE.

This is the code to write CSV File

```
   if(write_into_csv && is_job_finished){


        String fileName = "/Users/amar/Desktop/out/join.csv";

        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/amar/Desktop/out/join.csv",true));
        writer.writeNext(new String[]{Integer.toString(WindowLength_join__ms), Integer.toString(number_of_joined_events)});

        writer.close();

    } //if(write_into_csv)
```

Output of this program is

[image]

As, I have to run this program multiple numbers of times, so I have made a bash file which runs the jar file the multiple numbers of times then run python file to generate graphs. 
Anyhow, the issue is that in case of bash file the output is something like this

[image]

> Why is second value zero?

Contents of bash file are

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
jarpath="/Users/amar/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP_Architectures/Mobile_CEP/classes/artifacts/cep_monitoring_jar/cep-monitoring.jar"
flinkpath="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.3.2/"
result_file_path="/Users/amar/PycharmProjects/untitled/join_graph.py"
# $flinkpath./bin/historyserver.sh start
for i in {1..3}
do
$flinkpath./bin/flink run $jarpath 500
$flinkpath./bin/flink run $jarpath 1000
$flinkpath./bin/flink run $jarpath 2000
# $flinkpath./bin/flink run $jarpath 2500
# $flinkpath./bin/flink run $jarpath 3000
# $flinkpath./bin/flink run $jarpath 3500
# $flinkpath./bin/flink run $jarpath 4000
done
# $flinkpath./bin/historyserver.sh stop
python $result_file_path
echo "program is complete"
```

Comment: Why do you declare `fileName`, but don't use it on the following line?

Comment: How do you populate `number_of_joined_events`?